# Edits to my firestore documents result in a new line item being added to the View/List rather than a realtime change to the original line item

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Can you help me understand why this code is misbehaving?  I have a List in a SwiftUI View that is populated by this function.  It is an array called 'players'.  It loads and the list looks great in the UI.  However, when I manually edit a document in firestore, a new line item appears with the edits rather than the edits being applied in realtime to the existing item.

Hope that makes sense.

Here is the code -

```
func getBuddies(arr: [String],completion:@escaping(([String]) -> ())) {
    var u: UserProfile = UserProfile(id: "", name: "", nickname: "", loginID: "", email: "", createdBy: "")
    //var newArr : [String] = []
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    for id in arr {
        g.enter()
        store.collection(path)
            .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), isEqualTo: id)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting > courses: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    u.id = document.documentID
                    u.name = document.get("name") as! String
                    u.nickname = document.get("nickname") as! String
                    u.email = document.get("email")  as! String
                    u.createdBy = document.get("createdBy") as! String
                    u.loginID = document.get("loginID")  as! String
                    
                    self.players.append(contentsOf: querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap {(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserProfile? in
                                            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserProfile.self)})
                    
                    g.leave()
                }
                
            }
    }
    
    g.notify(queue:.main) { [self] in
        print("NEW ARRAY: \(players)")
        completion(arr)
    }
    
}
```

UPDATE::

I have also tried to process the callback according to the transaction type - the following works fine for adds but I'm not sure how to handle changes and deletes.

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    u.id = document.documentID
                    u.name = document.get("name") as! String
                    u.nickname = document.get("nickname") as! String
                    u.email = document.get("email")  as! String
                    u.createdBy = document.get("createdBy") as! String
                    u.loginID = document.get("loginID")  as! String
                    
                    querySnapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                        if (diff.type == .added) {
                            self.players.append(contentsOf: querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap {(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserProfile? in
                                                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserProfile.self)})
                            print("New player: \(diff.document.data())")
                        }
                        if (diff.type == .modified) {
                            print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
                        }
                        if (diff.type == .removed) {
                            print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
                        }
                    }

                    
                    g.leave()
                }
```

Comment: Your snapshot listener only calls `self.players.append`. So, any new snapshot (whether it's a new item or an edited previously-existing item) is only going to get added to the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, jnpdx!  Note the update above where I am tinkering with handling the type of transactions differently.  Adds are working in this model but I am not sure what to put for mods and dels.